# Return to the previous activities

Tags: android

In my app I have situations where I need to get a user back to some activity that preceded(not necessarilly directly) the current one. All of those previous acitivities might need Intent parameters in onCreate.

So, my question is there any easy way to get user back to an activity that might not be the direct previous activity he's been on and is it possible to  avoid manual workaround of saving/restoring those previous activities' intent parameters ?

Consider an example: there's a global search-bar that can provide users with suggestions on products; once they hit one of suggested items they get moved on a product-view activity where they can reload this activity with another product - walk through. After a couple of such reloads they might decide to go back to the activity where the search was initiated, but it might not the closest to the current one.

UPD: There also should be a possibility to go back in B activities sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Using `startActivityForResult()` while loading a new activity and using `finish()` to close the launched activity on back press can solve your problem.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning, but it's also needed to be able get back in B activities sequence. There're two buttons: one is for return to the higher element in hierachy and the other - to go back to the previous product item if there's any.

Comment: Use the function `setResult(resultCode, data)` before finishing an activity (say Activity C) which was launched using `startActivityForResult()`(say from activity B). When the method `onActivityResult()` is called in activity B you can verify the `data` and then determine if you want to finish this activity(and show Activity A) or stay on Activity B.

Comment: If you don't have any significant `data` then you can use just set the result using `setResult(id)` and based on this `id` you can perform various operation in `onActivityResult()`.